# What's similar to an #ifdef DEBUG in R?

Tags: r

I'm writing R code where I would like to have it run either in "non-debug" or "debug" mode. Under the debug mode, I would like the code to print-out runtime information.

In other languages, I would typically have some sort of print function that does nothing unless a flag is turned on (either for compilation or runtime).

For example, I can use #ifdef DEBUG (in compilation time), or set a debug level in run time.

What would be the equivalent way of doing this in R?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Same thing, minus the preprocessor:

- Define a global variable variable (or use an `options()` value)
- Insert conditional code that tests for the variable
- Works with your functions (adding `..., verbose=options(myVerbose))`, in your packages, etc pp
- I have also used it in R scripts (driven by [littler](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/littler.html)) using the CRAN package [getopt](http://cran.r-project.org/package=getopt) to pick up a command-line option `--verbose` or `--debug`.

Answer (score 4):

A slightly fancier version of Dirk's answer:

```
is_debug_mode <- function()
{
  exists(".DEBUG", envir = globalenv()) && 
    get(".DEBUG", envir = globalenv())
}

set_debug_mode <- function(on = FALSE)
{
  old_value <- is.debug.mode()
  .DEBUG <<- on
  invisible(old_value)
}
```

Usage is, e.g.,

```
if(is_debug_mode())
{
  #do some logging or whatever
}
```

and

```
set_debug_mode(TRUE)   #turn debug mode on
set_debug_mode(FALSE)  #turn debug mode off
```

Answer (score 2):

It might also be worth looking at the `Verbose` class in the [R.utils](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/R.utils/index.html) package, which allows you very fine control for printing run-time information of various sorts.

Answer (score 1):

Extending Richie's code:

also, you can check for the system environment variable DEBUG for initialization:

```
    isdbg <- function()
{
  if(exists(".DEBUG", envir = globalenv()))
  {
    return(get(".DEBUG", envir = globalenv()))
  } else #initialise from shell environment variable
  {
    debugmode <- !(toupper(Sys.getenv("DEBUG")) %in% c("", "FALSE", "0"))
    assign(".DEBUG", debugmode, envir = globalenv())
    return(debugmode)
  }
}

setdbg <- function(on = FALSE)
{
  old_value <- isdbg()
  .DEBUG <<- on
  invisible(old_value)
}

ifdbg <- function(x)
{
    if(isdbg()) x   
}
```

usage:
    setdbg(TRUE)   #turn debug mode on
    setdbg(FALSE)  #turn debug mode off

```
if(isdbg())
{
  #do some logging or whatever
}
```

or

```
ifdebug(...do something here...)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility is [log4r](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/log4r/index.html)

To quote this page:

> log4r: A simple logging system for R, based on log4j
>
> logr4 provides an object-oriented logging system that uses an API
>   roughly equivalent to log4j and its related variants.