# avoiding browser calls in R

Tags: debugging, r, browser, non-interactive

I have an elaborate script that spans multiple functions (and files). For debugging purposes I need to embed `browser` calls into all sorts of nooks and crannies. When I presumably fix something, I want to run the whole thing without debugging, ergo avoiding `browser` calls because commenting out all browser calls would mean a considerable effort from my part. @mdsumner on R chat suggested running the script in non-interactive mode (i.e. using Rscript.exe on Windows) but I would benefit from having that done in my console, to be able to access for instance `traceback`. I have gone through browser docs and I can find no option that would come close to what I'm trying to achieve. Any suggestions?

Comment: Have a look at the answers to this very similar question that was posted recently: http://stackoverflow.com/q/6286092/602276

Comment: I will use `options(debug = "FALSE")` and inside a function: `if (options("debug")) browser()`. Thanks!

Comment: wrap that inside a function definition called 'dbrowser' and replace all your browser() calls with dbrowser() - instead of replacing them with an if(options)-browser two-liner.

Comment: Good advice, @Spacedman. Care to write that down in a form of an answer so I can upvote you?

Comment: @Spacedman Isn't this make `browser` to browse `dbrowser` function?

Comment: Yes it will. And @Roman I think it should be `getOption("debug")` cause `options("debug")` returns `list` and is not interpreted as logical condition.

Comment: ouch yes. is there some way of telling browser to knock it up a level? I can't seem to get skipCalls to do what I think it should... Ah, it just changes the report, not the environment context...

Comment: Would sure love to hear what caused the downvote on this one.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here are three possibliities:

1) **Overwrite browser command**. Add this command to your global workspace to turn the browser commands off:

```
browser <- list
```

and to turn it back on

```
rm(browser)
```

This is probably the easiest but is a bit ugly due to the `browser` variable being left in the global environment.

The next two solutions are slightly longer but use options instead so that no new variables are introduced into the global environment.  Also they are such that if no options are set then no debugging is done so you only have to set an option if you want debugging. The `if` solution may be faster than the `expr` solution although its likely not material.

2) **Use expr= argument with option**.  Replace each browser command with:

```
browser(expr = isTRUE(getOption("Debug")))
```

and then define the `"Debug"` option to be `TRUE` to turn debugging on.

```
options(Debug = TRUE)
```

or set it to something else or remove it to turn debugging off:

```
options(Debug = NULL)
```

3) **Use if with an option**.  Replace each browser command with:

```
if (isTRUE(getOption("Debug"))) browser()
```

and then set the `Debug` option or not as in the prior point.

Comment: All good comments from Michael and Marek, but I'm choosing this one as the correct one as it has an overview of three methods.

Answer (score 4):

Define global logical value

```
debug_mode <- TRUE
```

and then instead of `browser()` use

```
if (debug_mode) browser()
```

Answer (score 2):

I think this just comes down to nuanced use of a debugging function. If you want to selectively control the use of `browser()`, put it inside an `if` that lets you enable or disable debugging for the function. When you want browser to be called, make that explicit like

```
myfun(x, debug =  TRUE)
```