# Checking within an R function whether it is being traced?

Tags: r, debugging, trace

I'd like to have the ability to control on a function-by-function level whether verbose debugging information is printed by an R function.   There are a number of ways to do this by checking a global variable ([What's similar to an #ifdef DEBUG in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6286092/whats-similar-to-an-ifdef-debug-in-r)) but I want something that integrates with R's existing `trace` functionality.  I haven't found a way to determine from within a function whether it is currently being traced.

I envision something like this:

```
> f = function(x) {
+   tracePrint("x is ", x)
+   x
+ }
> f(1)
[1] 1
>
> trace(f)
> f(1)
trace: f(1)
  x is  1
[1] 1
> untrace(f)
> f(1)
[1] 1
>
```

Is there any way to write a tracePrint() function that prints the arguments when the caller is being traced, but otherwise does nothing?

I'd happily settle for a "if (traced()) print(x)" syntax if this is easier, but definitely want a system that where the control is done through trace()/untrace(), and the extra functionality of these is still available separately.

In a pinch I guess I could redefine these to set a flag in a global indexed by function name (or maybe an attribute on the function itself?), but it seems like there should be a more elegant way to accomplish this.

Comment: For a function `f = function(x) x` you can say `trace(f, tracer=quote(print(paste("x is", x))))` instead of trace, and get the behavior that you describe; is that what you're looking for, perhaps implementing a more general version of the expression `quote(print(paste(...)))`?

Comment: Yes, there are exciting things that you can do with trace.  My hope is to keep those accessible while adding the ability to have custom low impact debug statements manually inserted into the code code.  My current use case is printing out multiple details about individual iterations deep within a regression.   While it would be possible to do this with the standard trace interface, it would be really fragile.  One way of viewing my desire is that I want to be able to define a default trace that travels with each function.

Answer (score 2):

A more traditional approach is to use something like [futile.logger](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/futile.logger/index.html).

I don't know that there's anything available, but poking around a little in the way a function is marked as being 'traced' lead to a C one-liner that tests whether a function is currently being traced

```
library(inline)
isTracing = cfunction(signature(fun="function"), body="
    return Rf_ScalarLogical(RTRACE(fun) ? TRUE : FALSE);
")
```

which works as

```
> f = function(x) x
> isTracing(f)
[1] FALSE
> trace(f)
> isTracing(f)
[1] TRUE
```

It would probably need to be used as `isTracing(f) && tracingState()` to catch the case when the global tracing state has been turned off.

This can be used for at least some function calls with `eval(sys.call()[[1]])` (I have no idea whether this is a good approach to identifying the called function), e.g.,

```
f = function() g()
g = function() isTracing(eval(sys.call()[[1]]))
```

In use:

```
> f()
[1] FALSE
> trace(g)
> f()
[1] TRUE
```

Becoming increasingly hacky, it seems that `trace()` uses classes derived from class "traceable" to mark a function / generic /method as being traced. So the test might be

```
tracing <- function(fun)
    tracingState() && (is(fun, "traceable") || isTracing(fun))
```

with

```
g = function() tracing(eval(sys.call()[[1]]))
```

This fails for (some) methods

```
.A = setClass("A", "list")
setGeneric("foo", function(x) standardGeneric("foo"))
setMethod("foo", "A", function(x) tracing(eval(sys.call()[[1]])))
trace("foo", signature="A")
foo(.A())                        # returns FALSE instead of TRUE
```

because `eval(sys.call()[[1]])` gets the generic rather than method

Comment: Good start! I tried to figure out what was happening at the C level (https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/trunk/src/main/debug.c) before asking but got lost, even though my C is usually stronger than my R.   Your approach seems to work in the simple case of trace(fun), but not in the more complex versions (as in your comment on main) that inserts custom code.   But in that case, the swapped in function is changed from class "function" to "functionWithTrace" (and any other classes disappear).     So maybe I can check "tracingState() && (isTracing(f) || class == "functionWithTrace)")?

Comment: I'm becoming less certain this can work.  It seems absurd, but I haven't yet found any reasonable way to get the current function from within a function. I'd presumed that sys.function() would suffice, but this duplicates cptr->callfun (https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/trunk/src%2Fmain%2Fcontext.c#L447) rather than returning the actual function, which results in RTRACE(sys.function()) always returning false.   Worse, there doesn't seem to be any legal way to get direct at the C level as an extension.  Here's the Rcpp11 approach: https://github.com/Rcpp11/Rcpp11/issues/216.  Yuck.

Comment: @NathanKurz added a little more